# Exception when trying to use projection for entity with clob type property in spring data

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

There is an entity with CLOB property:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "clob")
  @Lob
  private String description;

  //getters and setters here
}
```

Now I would like to have a method that can return only part of this class, so here is a projection class:

```
public interface PersonProjection {
  String getLastName();
  String getDescription();
}
```

and the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select pe.last_name as lastName, pe.description from person pe where pe.last_name = :lastName", nativeQuery = true)
  List<PersonProjection> findAllByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
}
```

Using native query in this example is not needed but in my case I would like to call an Oracle's function in the `where` clause (`JSON_TEXTCONTAINS` to be specific).

Now using this repository in the controller causes:

```
Could not write JSON: Projection type must be an interface!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Projection type must be an interface! (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103[\"description\"])
```

Exception seems to be caused because query returns `description` field as an instance of `java.sql.Clob` interface, but in projection class this field is defined as `String`. Exception is not thrown when entity class is used as a return type from repository method (and there `description` is also defined as a `String`).

Complete project to check this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/piotrchowaniec/clob-native-projection).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I've run into the same use case and am stuck.

Comment: @AndreasSJ No, I did not. My workaround is to use entity class in the repository find... method as a result and then manually convert entity to required projection class.

Comment: A nice fix that worked for me on PostgreSQL (but I think would on Oracle too): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377158/how-to-show-clob-type-in-a-select-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

you can parse clob to varchar in  sql.
Ex: dbms_lob.substr( pe.description, 4000, 1 ) as description